# Can't fix ImageView inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an ImageView aligned to the right of a TextView. When the text is too long, it resizes the image... How can I keep the same size for the image and force the TextView on a new line?

Short text, good size:
[image]

Long text, bad size:
[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_container_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:onClick="searchClicked"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_text_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="BTN1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_image_1"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btn_text_1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_text_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/draw" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try  android:ellipsize="end"  in  Textview tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a nested linear layout to do so like the following:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_container_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_weight=".50"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:onClick="searchClicked"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_text_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="BTN1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_image_1"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/draw" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Linear layout with horizontal orientation instead of relative layout and set weight for both textview and imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Do not hard code any attribute it will create issue at later point if screen size changes try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:text="button"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:onClick="searchClicked"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_text_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="BTN1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_image_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:src="@drawable/state" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you try this, if it is not working send me you screen how you want to design.I will help you.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="est.androidapplication.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_text_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ff0044"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1BTN1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_image_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use weight of textview in linear layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true">

     <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="BTN1"/>
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="30dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:background="#344"/>

 </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```